# Wireshark - Capture syslog traffic form local workstation

Tags: syslog, wireshark

I am using wireshark version 1.10.3 on windows 7 x64 enterprise.  I am trying to capture all outbound UDP traffic, in particular syslog traffic.

I have tried a capture filter UDP, but all I can see it DNS and NTP traffic.

I have used the following script to send UDP messages to a remote syslog server.

$syslogClient = new-object system.net.sockets.udpclient syslog_server_ip, 514;

$message = "Test syslog  $(get-date)"

[byte[]] $rawMSG = $(new-object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetBytes($message)

$syslogClient.Send($rawMSG, $rawMSG.Length);

$syslogClient.close();

The messages get to the syslog server but I cannot see them within the wireshark capture window.

Has anybody managed to capture outbound syslog messages within wireshark, or is there something that I am missing?

Regards,
David

Comment: Yes, I "manage" to use Wireshark all the time. Are you capturing on the correct adapter? Start without a filter and go from there.

Comment: Also, post your capture filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO Easiest way is to capture UDP port 514. `udp.port==514`

Alternatively you can try to capture all traffic going to `ip.addr=="Your Syslog Server"`

Comment: Those are display filters, not capture filters.

Comment: Used NO capture filter and set display filter to udp.port==514  I have also reinstalled my OS since and have a clean install of wireshark.  Its working perfectly now.  Thanks guys!